# what is the relation between diagonal Ramsey numbers $R(r,r)$ and Turán number $t_r(n)$?

Tags: ramsey-theory

Ramsey numbers are mostly unknown,I have seen bounds on Ramsey numbers ( for example via the probabilistic method)
but there is more information about Turán numbers, , and i can't find in the internet a bound on the diagonal Ramsey numbers based on known Turan numbers.

Here is why i am suspicious that such a relation must exist :
If we consider 2-coloring of the complete graph $K_n$ and we regard (say) only red edges, then if there is more than $t_r(n)$ red edges then there must be a red clique of order $r$,and on the other hand if there is this much blue edges we have a  blue clique of size $r$,so a bound must exist which relates Ramsey number $R(r,r)$ to the Turan number $t_r(n)$.

Please help if you know such a relation (I couldn't find such a result in the older posts). I think something like :
smallest number $n$ such that $${n \choose 2}- t_r(n) > t_r(n)$$

Comment: this statement of yours: "...No matter how big n is, if half the edges are red and half are blue, there are not enough edges of one color for the sheer number of edges to force a triangle, and not nearly enough to force a larger complete graph" is not true! ( it is in direct contradiction with the very Ramsey theorem, because for enough large n , "ANY 2-coloring" whether it be half red-half blue will contain complete monocromatic cliques)....consider it again...

Comment: i understood that my guess inequality above is wrong , but the question still remains....( i will try to formulate and state my idea in a better way)

Comment: guys , i just think the following relation please commnet what you think :

Comment: n must be so large that : $${n\choose 2} > {r\choose 2} + t_r(n)$$